# Visual C++ open a file by relative path

Tags: visual-c++, io

How can I open a file in Visual C++ 2010, with a relative path?

I used to use `C:\\test.txt` to open a file. Now I moved the file into the project directory so it can be under version control and others can open the file too. But `test.txt` does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might want to try

> ..\test.txt